# Replace dates in a file with date-n hours

Tags: regex, bash, perl, awk, sed

I'm trying to replace occurrences of a date formatted as YYYYMMDDHHMMSS with the that time minus 7 hours.

The file would look like this

```
File with text and some dates 20140716223000 20140716013000
```

and I would like the output to look like

```
File with text and some dates 20140716153000 20140715183000
```

The best I could come up with was a perl subsitition:

```
perl -ape 's/(-*\d+.\d+)/$1-70000/ge' file.txt
```

but obviously this isn't doing date subtraction, but simple arithmetic. Any bash or perl statement will work for me. Perhaps a sed or awk statement? Thanks!

Comment: I think regex doesn't do any processing on the output. regex is not meant for programming.

Comment: Perl will let you use a function in the output of a replacement. Perhaps awk is better suited for this?

Comment: @Braj: Perl is not Java, and it is capable of very different things

Comment: @Borodin nice to know about it. Perl is great.

Comment: To subtract seven hours, you'd need to know the time zone of the timestamp. Otherwise, it can occasionally subtract 5, 6, 8 or 9 hours instead. It can also result in times that don't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU awk for gensub() and time functions:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    head = ""
    tail = $0
    while ( match(tail,/\<[[:digit:]]{14}\>/) ) {
        oldTime = substr(tail,RSTART,RLENGTH)

        secs = mktime( gensub(/(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)/,"\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4 \\5 \\6","",oldTime) )
        newTime = strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S", secs - (7 * 60 * 60))

        head = head substr(tail,1,RSTART-1) newTime
        tail = substr(tail,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print head tail
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
File with text and some dates 20140716153000 20140715183000
```

Comment: I did the same thing! Except I ignored fields, used `match` on `$0` and rebuilt it with `substr` (and `RSTART`, `RLENGTH` from `match`).

Comment: I started with a loop on fields then switched to a match too to avoid trashing white space. Looks like I was finishing that off while you were posting your comment. Great minds... :-)

Comment: Cool. I actually used a bunch of `[0-9]{n}`'s in my `gensub`, but your `.` idea is perfect since we've already determined that they're digits with the `match`. You even have the word boundaries in there. And you got drive-by downvoted too! Oh well. C'est le vie sur le SO.

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time::Piece) to parse the date-time string and do the arithmetic. It has been a core module since version 10 of Perl 5 and so shouldn't need to be installed.

The related [`Time::Seconds`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time::Seconds) module provides useful constants for various time intervals in seconds.

This program does as you require using an executable substitution as you do in your question. Note that it won't handle daylight saving periods properly as it just does a simplistic subtraction of 25,200 seconds from each value.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds qw/ ONE_HOUR /;

my $text = 'File with text and some dates 20140716223000 20140716013000';

say "Before: $text";

$text =~ s{(\d{14})}{
  my $dt = Time::Piece->strptime($1, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S');
  $dt -= 7 * ONE_HOUR;
  $dt->strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S');
}ge;

say " After: $text";
```

**output**

```
Before: File with text and some dates 20140716223000 20140716013000
 After: File with text and some dates 20140716153000 20140715183000
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have GNU Bash, you most probably have GNU Coreutils too, so why don’t you use GNU `date`?

```
$ cat file
File with text and some dates 20140716223000 20140716013000

$ cat script 
#!/bin/bash

while read -a LINE; do
    for i in "${!LINE[@]}"; do
        [[ ${LINE[$i]} =~ ^[0-9]{14}$ ]] && {
            DATE="${LINE[$i]}"
            YEAR="${DATE:0:4}"
            MONTH="${DATE:4:2}"
            DAY="${DATE:6:2}"
            HOUR="${DATE:8:2}"
            MINUTE="${DATE:10:2}"
            SECOND="${DATE:12:2}"
            NEWDATE="$(date -d \
                "-7 hours ${YEAR}-${MONTH}-${DAY}T${HOUR}:${MINUTE}:${SECOND}" \
                +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S')"
            LINE[$i]="$NEWDATE"
        }
    done
    echo "${LINE[@]}"
done < "$1"

$ ./script file
File with text and some dates 20140716153000 20140715183000
```

Comment: Among other things, that would convert all white space to single blank chars and strip backslashes from the text. It would also fail to recognize date/time stamps that were surrounded by punctuation instead of white space. Try adding a literal tab char and a backslash and ending the line with a period to the OPs original input and note the undesirable effects of each then compare that to the awk script I posted. Shell is just an environment from which to call tools and the standard UNIX tool for processing text is awk.

Answer (score -1):

Not all questions should use regex.

How about using Date::Calc? it has a function that are exactly what you need:

```
($year,$month,$day, $hour,$min,$sec) = Add_Delta_DHMS($year,$month,$day, $hour,$min,$sec, $Dd,$Dh,$Dm,$Ds);
```

And you can use a simple regex to break the date-strings to year/month/day/hour/min/sec variables.and the $Dx parameters can be negative.

On a note, I hope that when you say "minus 7 hours" you are not trying to do timezone math. because that is a different question with a different solution.

Comment: Yes, but Time::Piece also does this easily, and has been a core Perl module for several years. I can't see any reason to ever use Date::Calc over Time::Piece or DateTime.